# Flatten curved surface

Tags: math, transformation, surface, flatten

I am trying to compute a panoramic projection for dental imaging purpose.

I have a rectangle surface "curved" in one direction by a piecewise function. If we look at it from the top, it looks like a regular piecewise function.

The "piecewise linear function" is just defined by a set of 3D points.
All the points are in the same plane. The plane where all the 3D points sit is orthogonal to the curved surface

(see the green line in the top-left window)

[image]

I am looking for the proper way to "flatten" it. (non linear transform)

The flat surface should have the same "length" as the curved one. (it is not a classic orthogonal projection)

Ultimately, I will use the "flat surface" as a canvas to display the information of interest.

(Bottom window)

[image]

Best,

Comment: It would be very difficult for us to say anything meaningful unless you give the details of the "piecewise function" that defines the transformation.

Comment: So the "piecewise linear function" is just defined by a set of 3D points.
All the points are in the same plane. The plane where all the 3D points sit is orthogonal to the curved surface. Does that help? Thanks

Comment: are the points sampled with constant density ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see it like this:

[image: img]

I would:

1. **take 3 consequent points `P0,P1,P2` from your curve**
2. **compute `U0,V0,U1,V1`**

   ```
   U0 = P1-P0
   U1 = P2-P1
   V0 = cross(U0,(0,0,1)); V0=half_height/|V0|
   V1 = cross(U1,(0,0,1)); V1=half_height/|V1|
   ```

   so `A,B` is just `P0 +/- V0` and `C,D` is `P1 +/- V1`. In the cross product Use any vector non parallel with `U0,U1` I chose `(0,0,1)` but in case it si parallel chose any other...
3. **make the `ABCD` a recangle**

   So compute `A'B'C'D'` for example

   ```
   A'.x = B'.x = index_of(P0) * sizex
   C'.x = D'.x = index_of(P0) * sizex + sizex
   A'.y = D'.y = sizey
   B'.y = C'.y = 0
   ```

   Where `sizex,sizey` is the size of rectangle segment. You can also use `|U0|,|V0|` but in that case the start `x` will be integrated curve length.
4. **compute transformation between `ABCD` and `A'B'C'D'`**

   so for each pixel P inside `ABCD` compute `(x,y)` inside `A'B'C'D'. The`x` is easy:

   ```
   x = A'.x + dot(P-P0,U0)/|P-P0|
   ```

   `y` is tricky and need some tweaking to suite your needs (so the result is smooth to your liking). For starters try simple approach (will lead to seams between segments)

   ```
   y = (A'.y+B'.y)/2 + dot(P-P),V0)/|P-P0|
   ```

   Now just copy the pixel at position `P` into your target image at position `(x,y)`

   To make this more smooth you can make `V` interpolated between `V0,V1` dependent on the `dot(P-P0,U0)/(|P-P0|*|U0|)` so it will change seamlessly.

   ```
   t = dot(P-P0,U0)/(|P-P0|*|U0|)
   V = V0 + (V1-V0)*t
   y = (A'.y+B'.y)/2 + dot(P-P),V)/|P-P0|
   ```

   If you need help with determining if point is inside then pixel `P` is inside if

   ```
   dot(P-P0,U0)/(|P-P0|*U0) = <0.0,1.0>
   ```
5. **loop #1 for all segments of the curve**

   step by single sample point of curve (not by 3 ...)

Comment: Thanks a lot, that is pretty much the big picture I had in mind - got to implement that in JS/WebGL now :)